# Binding an ObservableCollection to GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ObservableCollection` called `LesElem` which contains

```
 public class ListBoxArticle :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int chap;

    public int Chap
    {
        get { return chap; }
        set
        {
            chap = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Chap");
            OnPropertyChanged("Article");
        }
    }

    private string article;

    public string Article
    {
        get { return article; }
        set
        {
            article = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Article");
            OnPropertyChanged("Chap");
        }
    }

    private bool isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    private float somme;

    public float Somme
    {
        get { return somme; }
        set
        {
            somme = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Somme");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertySomme)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertySomme));
    }
}
```

I fill in in this way

```
public ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle> LesElem { get; set; }
List<ListBoxArticle> check = new List<ListBoxArticle>();

    private void SelectArt_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Remplissage des Elements Sélectionnés
        check.AddRange(LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true && !check.Contains(x)));
        LesElem = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle>(check);
    }
```

and I want to bind it to a Grid view

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="ToConfirm" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LesElem}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="ListArtChap">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Chap"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Chap}" Width="123"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Art"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Article}" Width="123"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Montant"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Somme}" Width="123"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

But my list is empty.
Some Help! Please

Comment: Is your model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: Please provide the code of the class, and where you instantiate the list

Comment: I made an edit @Joker_37

Comment: Provide the code where you fill the ObservableCollection

Comment: @rokkerboci actually i have two windows, in the first i'm adding items to my collection, when i finish i click a button in order to display this collection in a gridview to confirm

Comment: Don't overwrite LesElem, instead add the checked elements to it directly.

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Which class/object is the owner of LesElem? And does it implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: ListBoxArticles is the owner of LesElem, and yes it implements the INotifyProperty

Comment: You need to share the collection between your two windows or somehow tell the other one when you select/deselect an item. If you're not doing that then one window isn't going to know what's going on in the other. Do you have any code does that sort of thing?

Comment: i added DataContext=this in the event of the button private void 
  Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridSel nw = new GridSel();
            nw.DataContext = this;
            nw.Show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Trying to implement you code. This works for me. please try to refer this. I have not done whole viewmodel thing and  `await Task.Delay(4000);` is added to check if it gets reflected when I add value after sometime in collection.

```
    ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle> myList = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         MYFun();
    }

    private async Task MYFun()
    {
        myList.Add(new ListBoxArticle { Article = "my", Chap = 1, IsChecked = true, Somme = 1 });
        ToConfirm.ItemsSource = myList;
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        myList.Add(new ListBoxArticle { Article = "my", Chap = 2, IsChecked = true, Somme = 2 });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a problem of dataContext? Because as I said, i have two windows, LesElems is filling in the first one

Comment: if you are using LesElems in both windows it should be declared in your viewModel.

Comment: what is a viewModel?

Answer (score -1):

```
    List<ListBoxArticle> check = new List<ListBoxArticle>();

    private void SelectArt_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Remplissage des Elements Sélectionnés
        check.AddRange(LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true && !check.Contains(x)));
        LesElem = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle>(check);

        OnPropertyChanged("LesElem"); // <-- something like this
    }
```

Comment: I havn't understand!

Comment: If a wpf binding fails (ie not pointing to any found property) WPF will swallow this, but show a first chance exception in the output log while debugging in VS. This can be a hint if the problem is related to a binding error.

Comment: Ahh theres your problem... You have to raise a propertychanged after you have updated the observablecollection-property.

Comment: How to do this please!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Either you trigger a propertychanged as shown. Or you make sure that the obs coll exists from the start (so that the binding picks it up) and then just change the contents of the collection in the checked-handler.

Comment: in .cs of this window i made this                                                   
        public GridSel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this; // I think that this data context is false !
        }